# Datetime field will not allow a NULL value in the request, however the query works correctly via PostgreSQL, how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, forms, datetime, backend

I have a working application that tracks the hiring process of applicants through five stages. I am trying to adjust it so that the user can manually enter a date rather than having the program automatically decipher it via a timestamp.

The problem I am having is there are scenarios where a date should be NULL (because this part of the process is not yet completed.) This is no issue when I run the query directly in PostgreSQL as seen below
[image]

However, you will see here, that a request from postman with a null value renders an error. My back end code features the same exact query as above and was working just fine until I tried to allow the passing of a null value. Why would this be??

[image]

My backend code is below

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const { queryInstance } = require("../db/connection");


/*GET ALL DATE REQUEST*/
const getApplicants = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const applicants = await queryInstance('SELECT * from applicants');
    res.json({ applicants });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
};

/*UPDATE STATUS DATA REQUEST*/
const updateApplicants = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const applicant_id  = req.params.applicant_id;
    const {recruiterscreen_completion, backgroundcheck_completion, interview_completion, paperwork_completion, drugscreen_completion, testing_completion} = req.body
    
    const applicants = await queryInstance(`UPDATE applicants SET recruiterscreen_completion = '${recruiterscreen_completion}', testing_completion='${testing_completion}', interview_completion='${interview_completion}', backgroundcheck_completion='${backgroundcheck_completion}', drugscreen_completion='${drugscreen_completion}', paperwork_completion='${paperwork_completion}' WHERE applicant_id = '${applicant_id}' returning *`);
    
    res.json({ applicants })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
};



/*ADD NEW APPLICANT REQUEST*/
const addApplicant = async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  const { store, first_name, last_name, position, recruiterscreen_completion,testing_completion,backgroundcheck_completion,interview_completion,drugscreen_completion,paperwork_completion, date_in } = req.body;

  try {
    const applicants = await queryInstance(`INSERT INTO applicants (store, first_name,last_name,position, recruiterscreen_completion,testing_completion,backgroundcheck_completion,interview_completion,drugscreen_completion,paperwork_completion, date_in) VALUES ('${store}', '${first_name}', '${last_name}', '${position}', '${recruiterscreen_completion}', '${testing_completion}', '${backgroundcheck_completion}','${interview_completion}','${drugscreen_completion}','${paperwork_completion}','${date_in}') RETURNING *`);
    res.json({ applicants });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
}; 


/*DELETE APPLICANT REQUEST*/
const deleteApplicant = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const applicant_id = req.params.applicant_id;
    const applicants = await queryInstance(`DELETE FROM applicants WHERE applicant_id = '${applicant_id}' RETURNING *`);
    res.json({ applicants });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
};



module.exports = 
{deleteApplicant,getApplicants,updateApplicants,addApplicant}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way you use quotes ' in your code statement:

```
SET recruiterscreen_completion = '${recruiterscreen_completion}'
```

The piece of SQL that you used for the NULL, is without the quotes and works fine. Your code should handle the quoting, depending on the input. I have no knowledge about Reactjs, but your code might vulnerable to SQL injection as well, please check if your code is using prepared statements. And if so, why it fails when you're using a NULL value.

Comment: So how would you suggest fixing this? Problem is some entries have a value and other are left NULL so the code needs to be able to accept entries under both instances